# Do all rules and lore go out the window if ysalamiri are used by Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force

For those who don't know, ysalamiri are in the Legends part of *Star Wars* - creatures that repel the Force. They seem to blunt the powers of anyone using the Force. If one of these creatures was used by a Jedi, who then kills another Jedi in anger - does the creature nullify any desire to change to the dark side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with the answers stating that it does not make a difference.  Drawing upon the dark side (as an angry jedi will) is both corrupting and addictive beyond the act you are committing with the force. See "forever will it dominate your destiny". Using the force while angry will make you more open to the dark side.

Ysalamiri will prevent you from touching the force and therefore anger will not open the jedi to the dark side.

Of course, the anger might point to self control issues and those will will haunt the jedi in the Ysalamiri free future.

Answer (score 5):

**NO**

Anger is an emotion, not a Jedi power. The [Ysalamiri](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ysalamir) repel the force.
So a Jedi doing killing somebody in anger will still be considered to "have slipped towards the Dark side".

**Jedi code**:

> There is no Emotion, There is only peace.
>
> There is no ignorance, there is knowledge.
>
> There is no passion, there is serenity.
>
> There is no death, there is the Force.

So that particular Jedi would have broken the first and third line of the code that is the core of Jedi teachings. He would be considered to be on the path of the Dark side.

**Sith code**:

> Through passion, I gain strength.
>
> Through strength, I gain power.
>
> Through power, I gain victory.
>
> Through victory, my chains are broken.
>
> The Force shall free me.

As you see Killing in anger fulfils the first line of the Sith code.
Wearing a pet wont change that.
If this person is remorseful after the act he or she can be redeemed. If they continue doing the "Sith-y" things they would just slip further down the dark path.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you didn't use the force to murder someone doesn't nullify that it is a "dark" act. You are still prone to slip without ysalamari influence.

Answer (score 0):

You would still slip to the dark side. Ysalamari would not protect you from acts of murder that would make you go down the dark path.